# How to modify subscribe result in angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, observable

I have an observable **this.result$** to which i am subscribing inside template . for e.g result is- [{id : "1", value: "test"}]. How can I add new object to this so that it become like this-
[{id : "1", value: "test"},{id : "2", value: "new"}]

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="result$ | async">
  <mat-select [compareWith] = "compareFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor = "let item of result$ | async" [value]="item">
       {{item.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to change the code for this.
In your .ts file for example:

```
objectList: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.result$.subscribe(r => {
         this.objectList.push(r);
    });
}

addNewObject(newObject: any): void {
   this.objectList.push(newObject);
}
```

In your .html file use this.

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="objectList && objectList.lenght > 0">
  <mat-select [compareWith] = "compareFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor = "let item of objectList" [value]="item">
       {{item.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add new element in a observable array like this

```
this.result$ = this.result$.pipe(map((r) => [...r, { id: "2", value: "new" }]));
```

Comment: returning object is not of array type. so here "r" is showing error. otherwise your code is right in case of array. thanks for the help